# In "scipy.integrate.odeint", what does the option "col_deriv : bool, optional" imply?

Tags: python

For example, if I have a matrix differential equation; $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=A(t).y$. Here my jacobian is the A(t) matrix. But what is derivative across the column or derivative across the row as it is mentioned in 'col_deriv'?

I have tried both col_deriv=0 and col_deriv=1, but the result does not change.

Answer (score 3):

If you provide a y-derivative or Jacobian function for the ODE function f(y,x), the matrix is, behind the scenes, passed as array with an implicit understanding on how to organize this data back into matrix form. The standard in numpy and several other languages is row-first, that is, the first array elements fill the first row, then the second row and so on.

However in Fortran, which is the language the library underlying odeint is or was originally implemented in, the standard is column first, the first data fill the first column first, then the second etc. Matlab being first conceived as script language for Lapack and other netlib.org Fortran libraries, inherits this preference.

So if you do not provide the Jacobian this flag has no influence, if you provide the Jacobian the difference from this flag is whether the Jacobian is used or its transpose. The second can be very wrong and slow down or even break the integration.

Using the Fortran-friendly column-first format might give a slight speed advantage due to less overhead or a more cache-friendly memory access pattern, but also quite possibly this does not suffice for a noticeable difference.